# Is 3200x1800 resolution possible in Hyper-V?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, grub, resolution, hyper-v

I've got a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro (Windows 8.1), which has a screen resolution of 3200x1800. I'm trying to run Ubuntu 14.04 in Hyper-V at full screen on it. I've tried the steps listed [here](http://nzbart.blogspot.se/2013/12/running-ubuntu-full-screen-under-hyper.html), but I can only get up to 1920x1080. Is this the hard limit, or am I not seeing the correct way to get the resolution up?

Comment: If you set it to 1920x1080 does the size of the Hyper-V Windows increase ? Could you post a image ?

Comment: @Devid the window does increase, but it's not full-size. Furthermore, setting the resolution to be 1920x1080 on my laptop doesn't fix this.

Comment: I just checked to see for my self but it seems as if the maximum resolution is 1920x1080. When I increased it to 10920x1200 it went back to being small again.

Comment: Is there any way to make it scale correctly on the 1920x1080 mode on my display?